# SQL: Select from three tables

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:

[image: My tables]

I wanna find the name of employee who placed the most expensive object.
'Locations were placed' is the entity resulted by resolving M:M relationship between 'Objects places' and 'Employees'.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: (No way. To tell the `most expensive object`, you'd need *price* - you only got *value*.)

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't stated whether its Oracle, MySQL... I have done it in SQL Sever

```
Select TOP(1) employee_name
FROM Employees e, Locations_Were_Place lwp, Objects_Placed op
WHERE e.employee_id = lwp.employee_id
AND lwp.inventory_number = op.inventory_number
ORDER BY op.[Value] DESC
```